# Increase salary by 10% for department with lowest average salary

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

This interview question solution does not work because I have two columns in the subquery and I can't use `LIMIT` if I use `IN` in place of `=` following the `WHERE` clause. I'm on MySQL.

```
UPDATE employees 
SET salary = salary + (0.10*salary) 
WHERE team = (
    SELECT team, AVG(salary) avg_sal
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY team ORDER BY avg_sal LIMIT 1)
```

The above query will raise the following error:
`SQL Error [1241] [21000]: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

If `IN` is used following the `WHERE` clause instead of `=` in the query above then it would raise the below error:

`SQL Error [1235] [42000]: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Expected solution as stated in the title:
`Increase salary by 10% for department with lowest average salary`

How can I rewrite this query to overcome this?

Comment: There is no question in this post. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* have the subquery return just the team instead of two columns. Probably, this is the query you wanted to write:

```
update employees e
set e.salary = 1.1 * e.salary
where team = (select team from employees group by team order by avg(salary) limit 1)
```

Unfortunately, this **would raise error**:

> You can't specify target table 'e' for update in FROM clause

That's a typical limitation of MySQL, that won't let you re-open the table that is being updated in the `where` clause. Instead, you can `join`:

```
update employees e
inner join (select team from employees group by team order by avg(salary) limit 1) e1 
    on e1.team = e.team
set e.salary = 1.1 * e.salary
```

Comment: I was referring to the order in which they are displayed above.. :-) Interestingly I did not get an error with either of your queries. MySQL Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))